# Embedding of cylinder submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M} := \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ and $p_0 = (1, 0, 0)$. Show that there is an open neighborhood $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of $p_0$ and an embedding $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \supset U \rightarrow f (U) = \mathcal{M} \cap W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

My attempt: $U := [0, 1) \times (\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, $W = B_\varepsilon (p_0)$, and

$f :
\begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon \\
\vartheta \\
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \vartheta \\
\sin \vartheta \\
\pm \sqrt{\varepsilon^2 + 2 (\cos \vartheta - 1)}
\end{pmatrix}
$

By construction, $f (U) = \mathcal{M} \cap W$ (in particular, $p_0 = f (0)$) and injective. Problem: $D f (0)$ doesn't exist, so I can't show that $f$ is an immersion and thus embedding. I would also like to use the inverse function theorem at $f^{-1} (p_0)$.

The Cartesian representation didn't bring me anywhere either. I would appreciate any hints.

References: For plots, http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/prodori/prodor_sf_eng.html. For finding $f$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere%E2%80%93cylinder_intersection#Intersection_is_a_single_closed_curve, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Intersection_of_a_sphere_with_a_more_general_surface.

Comment: Why not use $\varepsilon\in (1/2,3/2)$?

Comment: @Ted: I did find another, somewhat more elegant parametrization: $U := (-\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3}) \times (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$, $W := \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (x - 1)^2 + y^2 < 1, |z| < \frac{1}{2} \}$, $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $\begin{pmatrix}
     \vartheta \\
     \varepsilon \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \mapsto
    \begin{pmatrix}
     \cos \vartheta \\
     \sin \vartheta \\
     \varepsilon \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R:\ (x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+y^2-1$. Then, the cylinder $\mathcal M$ is given by $g^{-1}(\{0\})$. By the regular level set theorem, $\mathcal M$ is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

You do not have to write out explicitly the slice chart, because seeing  this in this special case is not hard: if we take $F:=(g,y,z)$ we note that since the Jacobian of $F$ is not zero at $(1,0,0),$ the inverse function theorem gives a chart $(W_{(1,0,0)},(g,y,z))$ in the atlas of $\mathbb R^3$ and then  $\mathcal (\mathcal M\cap W_{(1,0,0)},(y,z))$ is a slice chart for $\mathcal M$ at $(1,0,0)$ (because $g$ vanishes on $\mathcal M$).

If $\pi$ is projection onto the $y-z$ plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and if we set  $U:=\pi(W_{(1,0,0)})$, then $f(y,z)=(\sqrt{1-y^2},y,z)$ maps $U$ onto $\mathcal M\cap W_{(1,0,0)}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and apologies for my late reply. You're certainly right, but the question is indeed about a parametrization $f$, as suggested.

Comment: I've asked a follow-up question about the level set theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566525/embedding-of-cylinder-submanifold-in-mathbbr3-level-set-theorem. Maybe you want to comment on this? (I would post my own answer here if it is confirmed in my course, because it features the asked-for function $f$.) Once again, thanks for you help. This is just not exactly what I am after, although certainly correct.

Comment: Isn't your parameterization essentially the same as the one (my $f$) in my snswer once you switch to polar coordinates?

Comment: Essentially, yes. However, the question is also about the sets. These are not trivial to find in this case (at least not for me), but they are critical to extend $f$ into a smooth diffeomorphism and derive a coordinate chart. That's why I hesitated to consider the question answered. Do you have any thoughts on my level-set question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566525/embedding-of-cylinder-submanifold-in-mathbbr3-level-set-theorem?

Comment: Since it's just a cylinder I think it should be easy to find a suitable W something like a cut sheath containing (1,0,0). I will look at the other question today. Thanks for your comment I am self studying diff geo myself so the feedback helps a lot