# Embedding of cylinder submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$: level set theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M} := \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ and $p_0 = (1, 0, 0)$. Show that there is an open neighborhood $W \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ of $p_0$ and a smooth submersion $h : W \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $h^{-1} (0) = W \cap \mathcal{M}$.

Obviously, $h : (x, y, z) \mapsto x^2 + y^2 - 1$ has $h^{-1} (0) = \mathcal{M}$ (kudos to [@Matematleta](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/138929/matematleta) for pointing this out.) It seems to me that a large enough neighborhood would thus trivially solve the problem. For example, $W := {(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 < 2}$ is open and $W \cap \mathcal{M} = \mathcal{M}$.

Is there also a more local solution—i.e., with a smaller set $W$? This question follows up on a question about parametrizing $\mathcal{M}$: [Embedding of cylinder submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557600/embedding-of-cylinder-submanifold-in-mathbbr3)), for which I used a smaller $W$.

Comment: How about a sheath of thickness $\epsilon$ about the cylinder? There is no "smallest" set $W$ but you can take $\epsilon$ arbitrarily close to zero. A more interesting question is (thinking of your other post about parametrizations and this one about restrictions of open sets) would be to find an atlas for the cylinder. For this, it won't do to simply take $\sigma(u, v) = (\cos v,\ sin v, u), u, v \in \mathbb R\ $ (why not?), but you can adapt this function to two $different$ open sets to make things work out.